# Why did I fail to find window use parent specified in Spy++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, findwindow, spy++

Imagine there is a web page with a `<input type="file" />`. I open this page in Firefox, and click on the file button. Then a dialog will popup.

I want to set the file name edit of the popup dialog programmatically in C++:

[image]

First I use Spy++ to check window class, the Firefox window and popup dialog properties in Spy++ look like:

```
Firefox window:
Handle:     001E013E
Caption:    Table with objects - Mozilla Firefox
Class:      MozillaWindowClass

Popup dialog:
Handle:     004508BE
Caption:    File Upload
Class:      #32770 (Dialog)
```

Spy++ also shows browser window is the parent of popup dialog.

My code looks like:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HWND hBrowser = FindWindow(L"MozillaWindowClass", NULL);
    printf("Browser hwnd=%X\n", hBrowser);

    HWND hDialog = FindWindowEx(hBrowser, NULL, L"#32770 (Dialog)", NULL);
    printf("Dialog hwnd=%X\n", hDialog);

    system("pause");
}
```

But the value of `hBrowser` does not equal the value in Spy++ dialog, and value of `hDialog` is `NULL`. I have only one Firefox window opened, with only one tab.

Then I tried to change my code to:

```
// 0x001E013E is the handle in Spy++
HWND hDialog = FindWindowEx((HWND)0x001E013E, NULL, L"#32770 (Dialog)", NULL);
```

`hDialog` still outputs as `NULL`.

Questions:

1. Why the handle in Spy++ and the one I get in program is not the same?
2. Does the "parent window" in Spy++ have the same meaning with the parent parameter in `FindWindowEx`?

> Note: I can't use window title to do the find, due to localization issue (Firefox may be installed in languages other than English).

Comment: At a guess, there's more than one MozillaWindowClass window, and the one you get from FindWindow isn't the one you're pointing at with Spy++.

Comment: @BobMoore I have only one Firefox window opened, with only one tab.

Comment: The edit fields in firefox are not win32 controls, you cannot change their contents with the win32 api.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I want to set file name edit in the popup dialog, not the edit in web page.

Comment: OK you should make that clear in the question.

Comment: class L"#32770 (Dialog)" not exist. need use L"#32770" in `FindWindowEx`

Comment: @AlexK. First I get HWND of MozillaWindowClass, then use it as parent HWND to find the File Upload dialog. I can't find the File Upload dialog directly, because in that way, I may find dialogs other than Firefox File Upload dialog.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry missed the 2nd part!

Comment: FindWindowEx searches through child windows.  Dialogs are popup windows not child windows.  Parts of the API and the MSDN documentation conflate parent-child relationships with owner-owned ones, but in some cases, the distinction matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MozillaWindowClass is the owner of the open dialog, it is not a parent you can use with `FindWindowEx`. There can also be more than one MozillaWindowClass window so it is better to look for the dialog first:

```
BOOL CALLBACK FindMozillaOpenFilenameDialogEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM param)
{
    HWND*pData = (HWND*) param;
    if (GetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCW_ATOM) == 32770) // Found a dialog?
    {
        HWND hOwner = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER);
        if (hOwner)
        {
            WCHAR buf[100];
            GetClassName(hOwner, buf, 100);
            if (0 == lstrcmp(buf, TEXT("MozillaWindowClass"))) // The dialog is owned by a Mozilla window?
            {
                HWND hCombo = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 0x047c); // cmb13
                GetClassName(hCombo, buf, 100);
                buf[8] = '\0'; // Some Windows versions use ComboBox and some use ComboBoxEx32, we only care if it is some type of combobox
                if (0 == lstrcmp(buf, TEXT("ComboBox"))) // The dialog contains a ComboBox with the expected ID?
                {
                    *pData = hWnd;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{

    HWND hDialog = NULL;
    EnumWindows(FindMozillaOpenFilenameDialogEnumProc, (LPARAM) &hDialog);
    printf("Dialog hwnd=%X\n", hDialog);
    if (hDialog)
    {
        HWND hCombo = GetDlgItem(hDialog, 0x047c);
        SendMessage(hCombo, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) TEXT("c:\\foo\\bar.exe")); // Could also use CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code relies on undocumented and internal names and window relationships, it could break at any time.

Keep in mind that "MozillaWindowClass" is a internal Mozilla name and could change at any time. The [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960#_win32_Explorer_Style_Control_Identifiers) cmb13 id of the filename control is only documented for `GetOpenFileName` and `GetSaveFileName` but not for [`IFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913) based dialogs. You really should use [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) when you interact with the open dialog in another application!